# How can I create a pull request from a fork without having created a branch on the fork?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I created a fork on Github, worked on the fork and now I want to create pull request for the original project to take my changes.

All the documentation I can find here, GitHub and Google refers to a branch being selected for the pull request, but I did not create one.

How can I proceed?

Comment: did you mix pull and push? Because you create a push request to bring your changes to a remote master where the remote master's owner decide to merge your stuff into his master. If you pull you get thing from the remote master into your own - current master (=a branch) or a new branch (=a branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch in git is just a pointer to a specific commit, nothing more.

When you fork a repo you take a copy of it and suddently you've two master branches. Our master branch, and the one in the forked repo.

Hence, you don't need to create a new branch. Let's say you forked the project *foobar*, did a commit to the master branch and then do a pull request. Github will descibe this as *robs_fork:master* -> *foobar:master*

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Is it rude to act in this way? is the origin less likely to accept the pull request?

Comment: I don't think it is rude, but using a separate branch increases clearity. It's hard to know that your branch master has bugfix A, but if your branch is named bugfixA it's easier to see.

Answer (score 2):

Create a branch from your local version

```
git checkout -b <your_branch>
```

Then push

```
git push <remoteName> <your_branch>
# note : <remoteName> is often "origin", depending on your config though
```

At this point your new branch `your_branch` will appear on your page for this remote on github, and you'll be able to create a pull request there to integrate your changes into the main branch.